# mailto fails to load email on Safari for iPhone, but works on iPad

Tags: html, iphone, mobile-safari, mailto

I was putting together a mobile website, and I wanted to create an email link that lets the user send links to their searches to other email address. The mailto link I generated  works fine in Chrome, IE, and Safari for the iPad. But on Safari for the iPhone, the link fails to bring up the default mail client.

```
<a title="Send search link" href="mailto:?subject=Check%20out%20Bob&body=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2FPeopleSearch%2F%3Fname%3DBob">Email your search results</a>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a lot of testing, and a lot of reading, I stumbled across this link to the iOS developer's website:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MailLinks/MailLinks.html

The key was this: ***"When specifying a mailto URL, you must provide the target email address."***

Basically, safari for iPhone requires a target email address in the mailto. With most other browsers, you can leave it blank. To fix the issue, I inserted a dummy email address to make it work.

```
<a title="Send search link" href="mailto:remove_this@email.com?subject=Check%20out%20Bob&body=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2FPeopleSearch%2F%3Fname%3DBob">Email your search results</a>
```

**EDIT:** This issue may no longer be the case for Safari browsers for iPhone version 7+.

Comment: Thanks for this.  It solved my problem.  It seems that Safari accepts only a "?" as the argument indicator for Subject.  Chrome, Firefox, IE, and the new Edge all accept "?" or "&".  However Safari accepts only "&" for the Body argument.  Weird on Safari's part, but it solves the problem.